# ServiceNow: list all legacy user role capabilities

Tags: servicenow

If I am developing on an instance of **ServiceNow** with many user roles defined and not a lot of documentation on the capabilities provided by the roles.

Is there any way to examine the SNOW instance and **determine capabilities** that a **role** provides the **end user**, even in such cases that a business or UI rule defines logic related to the role?

Could this be done through a backend script reliably?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't terribly straight forward documentation-wise or programmatically.

Your main option is to query the `sys_security_acl_role` table for a role and list the related ACL.

Also most ACLs don't have a proper description and the *advanced condition* would require you to read those as well if there is no *role* associated to an ACL.

You will need to look at the `name` and `operation` of the ACL to grasp what access they grant.

An example that you can run as  *Background script*

```
var role = 'itil'; // role to check

// query the ACLs with the role related
var gr = GlideRecord('sys_security_acl_role');
gr.addQuery('sys_user_role.name', role);
gr.query();

while (gr.next()) {
    // only show active ACLs
    if (gr.sys_security_acl.active) {
        gs.print(gr.sys_security_acl.name + " (" + gr.sys_security_acl.operation + ") - " + gr.sys_security_acl.description);
    }
}
```

The output depends on your instance, but this is the idea.

```
new_call (create) - Allow create for records in new_call, for users with role itil.
ngbsm_view (create) - Allow create for records in ngbsm_view, for users with roles (itil, ecmdb_admin).
...etc...
```

Comment: Thanks Kirk, appreciate your input, but that wont cover things like business rules with `if gs.getUser().getRoles().indexOf() == -1` for example, just wondering how people go about finding all references to a role. May have to ask SNOW for their input directly I think, doesn't seem to me that there is a viable option for uncovering potentially problematic legacy roles out of the box.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe there is a way to do a full inventory for a role. A lot of it would be a manual inspection and there are changes in every feature upgrade that aren't documented.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code may be use

```
function getUserGroups(user_sys_id) {  
        var theUser = gs.getUser();  
        theUser = theUser.getUserByID(user_sys_id);  
        return theUser.getMyGroups();  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one also

```
function setGroupFilter(){
    var user = current.variables.user_name;

    //Reset the filter query
    current_groupsg_filter.reset();

    var answer = 'sys_idINjavascript:getMyGroups()';

    current_groupsg_filter.setQuery(answer);
    current_groupsacRequest(null);

    //if remove reqeust display slushbucket
    if (addYN=="remove"){
    g_form.setDisplay('current_groups', true);
    }

    }
```